# Like button error: saying "fb:admins" meta tag not present when it is

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Please help I keep on getting this error:

The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users.

when trying to implement the Like button on this page

http://www.good-at-maths.com/aqa-gcse-maths-past-paper-solutions/

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that error when I run the page through the debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.good-at-maths.com%2Faqa-gcse-maths-past-paper-solutions%2F

Have you since resolved the problem?